# OpenGL glValidateProgram error on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl

I am trying to write a simple OpenGL 3.2 (with GLSL 1.5) program using GLUT on Mac OS X (Mountian Lion), but I keep getting error from glValidateProgram:

'Validation Failed: Current draw framebuffer is invalid.'

What could cause this error to occur?

Comment: This is going to sound flippant, but... an invalid draw framebuffer is what causes this to happen. Have you changed it? What is it currently?

Comment: Nicol is right as usual.  Also, glCheckFramebufferStatus could be your  best friend here.

Comment: glCheckFramebuffertatus returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED, which according to OpenGL reference means:

"returned if target is the default framebuffer, but the default framebuffer does not exist."

What can I define the default framebuffer?

Comment: Why would you need a framebuffer to compile a program? I cry "Apple driver bug": this is easy to reproduce simply by firing up additional threads and doing MT rendering, both on OSX and iOS. The rendering works fine, but apple (incorrectly, so far as I can tell) complains.

Comment: @Adam: This is a validation error, not a compile or link error. The purpose of validation is to determine whether or not the program is compatible with the current OpenGL state. In OP's case there's no valid draw framebuffer bound, so validation fails. This is not an "Apple driver bug", it's the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Like the OP i have encountered some code that uses this, and without knowing any better I implemented it immediately after the program link step. Got the same error.

I am no expert here but based on a few observations i thought I'd clarify what @robinjam seems to be saying (which echoes what the GL docs say about `glValidateProgram`).

The sample code I was using was Apple's iOS test OpenGL ES 2.0 demo project, and I haven't run this exact piece of code on a device yet but the Simulator gives me this `Validation Failed: Current draw framebuffer is invalid.` error. However, it is relevant to note that the method which runs this, `- (BOOL)validateProgram:(GLuint)prog`, is included in the `ViewController.mm` (not `.m` because I infected it with C++ early on) but *there is no code provided with this sample code that actually calls it*.

So the purpose of glValidateProgram is not to use it as an added "check" step after linking the program, because the GL and application state is hardly ready for actually *using* that program at this point, probably it's even before we get around to initializing the default framebuffer (its bitdepth, its multisample buffers, etc), and that's what the error hints at.

An appropriate place to call glValidateProgram would be right before you make a real render call.

It would be useful for debugging. It's an optional way for us to give a way for the driver to help us out when something seems to have gone wrong. It would be silly to call this every time we render in a non-debugging situation where everything is working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps, the code below creates a valid frame buffer for writing that is different from the default screen render buffer, writes to it then resets the screen buffer.

```
// ************************************** Save the Current Viewport Size

GLint screenViewPort[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, screenViewPort);

// ***************************** Define a Second Output Buffer and Bind it for Writing

glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, wispSecondOutputBuffer);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, wispSecondOutputBuffer[0]);

// ******************************* Set the Viewport to the Texture Size and Reshape

glViewport(0,0,TEXTUREWIDTH, TEXTUREHEIGHT);
[self resizeTextureGL]; // Calculates new Model, View and Projection Matrices

// ************************************** Create the Output Imgage Texture

glGenTextures( 1, wispOutputTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, wispOutputTexture[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (GLsizei)TEXTUREWIDTH, (GLsizei)TEXTUREHEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// ********************************* Attach the Output Texture to the Frame Buffer

glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, wispOutputTexture[0], 0);

GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

// ************************************ Check that the Frame Buffer is Complete

GLenum frameBufferStatus;

frameBufferStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT);

if(frameBufferStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT) NSLog(@"There is a problem with the output frame buffer");

// ****************************************** Render to the Texture

[self runTextureShaders];
[self runTextureShaders2];

// ************************************ Reset the Viewport and Frame Buffer

glViewport(screenViewPort[0],screenViewPort[1],(GLsizei)screenViewPort[2], (GLsizei)screenViewPort[3]);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's old question.

When I use GLKView and GLKViewcontroller in iOS, trying validation in viewDidLoad makes this error.

Do it in ViewDidAppear when the framebuffer is ready.